# Typescript path alias making imports possibly "undefined"

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to create path aliases to reduce the length of my import paths but I have run into strange situation where my imports (using these aliases) are now possibly "undefined".

**tsconfig.ts**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@/locations/*": ["./app/(site)/(content)/events/locations/*"],
      "@/location/*": ["./app/(site)/(content)/events/locations/[location]/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "create-env.js"]
}
```

**Imports:**

```
import {
  FacilityCard,
  LocationDescription,
  LocationGallery,
} from '@/location/components';
```

**Error:**

```
'FacilityCard' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2786)
```

Comment: It doesn't say that `FacilityCard` is possibly `undefined`, but its return type. Maybe check the render function

Comment: @DustInComp, you are correct, see my answer below, I had not made use of the components until I added the alias, otherwise I would have seen this right away.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this problem is NOT related to typescript path aliases, the affected imports all contain a null check that can result in a possible undefined return value.

thanks to @DustInComp for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If your null checks looks something like `if (requiredProp == null) return`, just make that `return null` instead and you should be good. I prefer conditionally rendering those components like `{requiredProp && <FacilityCard requiredProp=...>}` instead.